# Realm generated code error : return type Integer not compatible with int

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using realm in my project with the following model class

```
@Data
@Type("user")
@Builder()
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "email"}, callSuper = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.KebabCaseStrategy.class)
public class User extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Id(IntegerIdHandler.class)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    @Ignore
    private String password;
    private boolean isAdmin;
    private boolean isSuperAdmin;
    private String createdAt;
    private String lastAccessedAt;
    private String contact;
    private String deletedAt;
    private String details;
    private boolean isVerified;
    private String thumbnailImageUrl;
    private String iconImageUrl;
    private String smallImageUrl;
    private String avatarUrl;
    private String facebookUrl;
    private String twitterUrl;
    private String instagramUrl;
    private String googlePlusUrl;
    private String originalImageUrl;
}
```

Most of those annotations are from lombok.

When I run my project, I get the following error

```
Error:(149, 20) error: realmGet$id() in org_fossasia_openevent_core_auth_model_UserRealmProxy cannot override realmGet$id() in User
return type Integer is not compatible with int
```

The weird part is that this error arises from realm generated code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try: `@NonNull private int id;`

Comment: Another thing you can try if the previous one fails is `@Required private Integer id;`

Comment: Turns out that libraries needed to have a custom realm configuration to export the models. That was the issue.